# How to prevent the ansible format from getting overwritten?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting

I am using this plugin for ansible: [ansible-vim](https://github.com/pearofducks/ansible-vim), I am installing it with lazy like this:

```
return {
  'pearofducks/ansible-vim',
  build = 'UltiSnips/generate.sh',
  lazy = false
}
```

When opening a file the filetype is set to `yaml.ansible` but I notice that the jinja blocks are not recognized until I set ft to `ansible` something like this:

Using `ft=yaml.ansible`:
[image]

Using only `ft=ansible:`

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is that "lazy"? Also you say that you are installing it "with lazy" but your sample says `lazy = false`so… "with lazy" or "without lazy"?

Comment: Hi, lazy is a plugin manager (https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim)

Comment: You can try `au BufRead,BufNewFile */playbooks/*.yml set filetype=ansible` in your config file. Change to expression to match your need (this one will only detect files in directory playbooks.